# javasetting jdbc driver for coldfusion (Railo) in Application.cfc

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, coldfusion, railo

I have never had a need to handle a JDBC driver and DB like this so any help is appreciated. But I am working an environment that prevents me from doing anything in the cfadmin.

In Railo under `webapps` I have a website folder called `cms`.  That folder contains a file structure you would expect, js, css, img, etc.

**It also has two additional folders:**

`/db/cms.sqlite.db`
`/jar/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar`

**Here is my `Application.cfc` code (cfscript):**

```
this.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = ["./jar/"], loadColdFusionClassPath = true, reloadOnChange = true, watchInterval=30};
obj = createObject("java", "org.sqlite.JDBC");
this.datasources["cms"] = {class:'org.sqlite.JDBC',connectionString:'jdbc:sqlite:webapps/cms/db/cms.sqlite.db'};
```

How can I get all this to work? I can get the DB to work if I copy the JDBC jar file to `/lib/ext`(so that datasources with connection string works for me).

Now I just have to access that JDBC jar file locally and make it accessible to form a connection string (and I don't know how exactly to do that...but I think I am close).

**Edit:**

Would this also work the same in Coldfusion 11?

Comment: Might be better off asking this one on the Railo list.  As far as CF11, I am not sure. My guess would be it does *not* work with dynamically loaded driver jars, and that you need to physically place the jar in the CF class path (lib/ext, WEB-INF/lib, etcetera...). If you cannot do that,  there are no other options I am aware of, aside from rolling your own connections, instead of using cfquery.  (But that is not what you are looking for, plus it has a number of disadvantages...)